# How to use controller array notation when a controller is "created on the fly"?

Tags: angularjs

I know how to use Angular's array notation for controllers when these are created "within an app", like this:

```
angular.module('appName').controller('controllerName', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
}]);
```

But what if I have a controller that is used "on the fly"?

I have a directive that creates a bootstrap-ui modal controlled by a controller created "in the moment", this is the code:

```
angular.module('appName').directive('ngConfirmClick', ['$modal', function($modal) {

    // Controller "on the fly"       
    var modalController = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.ok = function() {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngConfirmClick:"&"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                var message = attrs.ngConfirmMessage || "Really?";

                var modalHtml = '<div class="modal-header"><h3 class="modal-title">Confirm</h3></div>'
                                + '<div class="modal-body">' + message + '</div>'
                                + '<div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>'
                                + '<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button></div>';

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    template: modalHtml,
                    controller: modalController, // Controller reference
                    backdrop: false,
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                    scope.ngConfirmClick();
                }, function() {
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Question is... how do I use array notation in here?

```
    // Controller "on the fly"       
    var modalController = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
        ...
    };
```

I know I could register the controller as I usually do with reusable controllers (see my first block of code)... but: should I? is it the only way?

This question can be abstracted and be helpful to others if stated as this:
If a directive needs to create/use a controller and this controller is used only by this directive and nobody else... how should the controller be created? within the app? within what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is already fine, you just need to assign `modalController` using the array notation. You don't need to add it as a reusable controller in the app since it's only used inside the directive.

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
var modalController = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.ok = function() {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}];
```

Alternatively, you can also add the dependencies using the `$inject` property.

```
var modalController = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.ok = function() {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};

modalController.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance'];
```

Comment: Great! two alternatives! Accepted. I thought about trying `var modalController = [...];` but I just dismissed that thought because it was weird that `modalController` is in fact an array

Comment: If you think about it carefully, the reusable controllers that you create are also arrays. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `$inject` property...

```
// Controller "on the fly"       
var modalController = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
    ...
};
modalController.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance'];
```